# broken HDD with /var /tmp inside.

Tags: boot, hard-drive, partitioning, tmp

My 2TB hard disk is broken. /var, /tmp and swap partition were in this drive. 
I can start ubuntu but only in text mode and wih limits.
How can I create /var and /tmp  inside / partition? 
Now /etc/fstab is changed without the broken hard drive but ubuntu tell me that /var is missing.

Answer (score 0):

- First, boot into recovery mode.
- Second, drop to root shell
- Third, run `mount -o remount,rw /`
- Fourth, `nano /etc/fstab` and remove the offending entries.
- Fifth, `reboot`; we are done here.